# Mailgun delivery-status 602 - too old

Tags: smtp, mailgun

2 days ago I started to receive a new status code 602 from mailgun when retrieving events from its  API

The returned response has

```
 "delivery-status": {
        "attempt-no": 8,
        "message": "Too old",
        "code": 602,
        "description": "",
        "session-seconds": 0
    }
```

What does "Too old" exactly mean here?  I cant find any documentation on the error codes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Been going around with Mailgun support on this very issue.

602 is an internal error code that they generate when a message can not be delivered to the recipient. The error is generated after they have attempted to send the messsage for eight hours.

Comment: Did you get any resolution on this?

Comment: I did correspond with Mailgun support & requested that they provide some kind of documentation of what this means / how we should be reacting to this... they were responsive and talked about creating some documentation for their internal response codes.

Comment: What does "attempting to send a message for 8 hours" mean?

Comment: @hashtable The SMTP protocol was designed in the days before dedicated connections. It was expected that two servers might not be able to conect for an extended period of time. The protocol itself is set up so that a message will be retried for a period of days if the receiving server is not able to accept the message. In this case, Mailgun is configured to "time out" after 8 hours of not being able to reach the recipient's server, or to otherwise send the message to the recipient's mail server.